# If my foreign key is unique in the target table, do I need a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`Object` stores static data, with PK `Object.Id`

`ObjectStatus` stores transient data, and is mapped 1:1 with `Object` so it has a FK `ObjectId` on `Object.Id`.

Given the FK is enforced unique and is the only sensible way to uniquely identify a record in `ObjectStatus`, is it sensible to make `ObjectId` the PK as well as a FK?

Comment: You probably need only one table

Comment: I think that would be bad normalisation @cid. And often, static data may be forbidden from being altered e.g. it belongs to the customer.

Comment: Your `objectId` will presumably have a unique clustered index on `objectId`, in which case you can make it the primary key of that table by definition. As it's the logical key you don't need to have any additional surrogate key, it's perfectly fine for it to be the tables primary key and also a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A relationship of this kind is a `1:0-1` or `one to zero or one`, and denotes that the data in the child table is optional relative to the main table.**

It is commonly used when there are a chunk of columns on the main table which are optional together, and is a perfectly legitimate way of setting up a database *if needed*. It's a bit like having a set of columns which are all `NULL` or all `NOT NULL`, but not a mix, such as an optional `Address`.

**You should still setup the primary key, but it will be the same column as the foreign key.**

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us which make and model of table server you use.

Many / most of them use a *clustered primary key* storage scheme, in which the index supporting the primary key also contains the table's data.  If there's no primary key the DBMS cooks one up for you under its covers so it has a way of storing the data.

So, your choice of a unique key that isn't primary, and omitting the primary key, probably has some negative performance (space and time) implications.

You'd be wise to use the unique key as a primary key. But your database will function correctly, if suboptimally, without it.

Comment: I  see. I figured a unique FK might remove the need but if the DBMS is going to make one anyway, I might as well specify it (and sorry, SQLServer, added that)

Comment: A PK can also serve as a FK.

Comment: Just to check is there a shortcut to combine the two or would I simply specify both as normal e.g.  `[ObjectId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectStatus_ToObject] FOREIGN KEY ([ObjectId]) REFERENCES [Obkect]([Id])`

Comment: @Mr.Boy There is no shortcut. And now would be a good time to contribute to the site by marking any of your questions as answered if they were, in fact, answered.

Comment: @SMor please don't misuse comments for lecturing. This is not what they are for.

Comment: @SMor `[ObjectId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES [Object]([Id])` would be shorter, although prob not recommended without a constraint name

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be:

1. Have a foreign key on ObjectStatus.ObjectId to Object.Id.
2. Add a field named something like AddDateTime to ObjectStatus to show when the row was added. Populate this with current date/time when adding a new row.
3. Make the primary key on ObjectStatus (ObjectId, AddDateTime).

This way you can track how and when the status of your object changed over time.